# production build is too big

Tags: reactjs, build

My src folder total size is 2.6 MB and the production build is 2.7 MB. It is taking too much time to load in the browser. I am generating a build using npm run build. I have started my project with `create-react-app` command. How to reduce the bundle size? Please help me.

I followed this link https://codeburst.io/how-i-cut-my-react-javascript-bundle-size-in-half-with-three-lines-of-code-fe7798ecbd3f as well but the result is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using,

- React's `lazy` and `suspense` modules.
- Using these modules directly for routes so for each route it will create a separate chunk.
- Trying to reuse most of the ui components so reduce the chunk size.
- Removed unwanted packages, code, css

To get performance benefits,

- For functional components, I am using React's `memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` modules.
- For class components, I am using `shouldComponentUpdate` or `React.PureComponent`.

For the projects which I setup myself without `create-react-app` or `vite`, I am doing code-splitting using `webpack` configurations.

I wrote a small blog for this. You guys can read it [here-on-medium](https://medium.com/@hardikchaudhary/code-splitting-4a3dfb177ed1).

Answer (score 0):

To increase loading performance of your app, another pointer could be using [code splitting feature](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) from webpack.

Or you can even consider Server-Side Rendering with react-based frameworks like [`nextjs`](https://nextjs.org/) or [`gatsby`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your application perforce there are some methods to follow

1. We have to use React Js latest version or above 16
2. We have to Remove unwanted imports in the components
3. Using shouldComponentUpdate()we have to control the rendering method, if its necessary then only render the component
4. Re Usable of components
5. Using Lazy Loading Concept we can increase the performance